# WSO2 IS - The getAllChallengeQuestions() API does not pull the already set challenge questions

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 IS version 5.3.
I created the set of challenge questions as per the WSO2 IS documentation - https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Challenge+Questions#ManagingChallengeQuestions-Addlocalemappingtoaquestion

But when i try to pull these challenge questions through SOAP UI using "getAllChallengeQuestions()" method of UserIdentityManagementAdminService, it does not pull the challenge questions from the Challenge Questions Set that i created.

Any thoughts on this will really help us in resolving this issue as we are completely stuck.

Here is the SOAP request for reference:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.mgt.identity.carbon.wso2.org">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getAllChallengeQuestions/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: What is the response you got as the result of the soap request?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, it indeed returns a response with the challenge questions that we created through  soap but it does not return the challenge questions set that was created from the IS console

Comment: <ns:return xsi:type="ax2391:ChallengeQuestionDTO" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2391:order>0</ax2391:order>
            <ax2391:promoteQuestion>false</ax2391:promoteQuestion>
            <ax2391:question>What was the name of your first pet?</ax2391:question>
            <ax2391:questionSetId>http://wso2.org/claims/challengeQuestion6</ax2391:questionSetId>
         </ns:return>